# How to Change icon in TinyMCE openmanger file uploader plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I'm using openmanger file uploader plugin for TinyMCE. Default icon for openmanager plugin look like this.

[image]

How can I change this icon and title(Files).???

Thank You,